# How do I structure Zend_Controller_Router_Route to handle the action and a param key in the same position?

Tags: zend-acl, zend-controller-router

Here is my route in JSON:

```
"jobs":
{
    "type":"Zend_Controller_Router_Route",
    "route":"/jobs/:action/:id/*",
    "defaults":
    {
     "module":"api",
     "controller":"jobs",
     "action":"index",
     "id":0
    }
}
```

This allows for URIs like the following and works perfectly well so far:

```
/jobs/ -> action=index, id=0
/jobs/view/1 -> action=view, id=1
/jobs/edit/1 -> action=edit, id=1
```

*However*, I would like the **:action** position to also allow for URIs like the following:

```
/jobs/type/volunteer -> action=index, type=volunteer
/jobs/search/php%20developer -> action=index, search=php developer
```

So far I'm accomplishing this within **App_Controller_Action::__call()**. It works, but it's messy because until the request is dispatched, the action is technically still listed as "search" or "term", and the value meant for those keys is assigned to id.

This is causing an issue in my Zend_Acl checks Im doing in a front controller plugin. As a workaround I've added "search" and "type" as permissions to my ACL but again, this is messy. The ACL should remain clean of those semantics. Id like for the request to be modified **before** it gets to the ACL plugin.